# Calculating force applied to an object to subtract health

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to calculate the force applied to my Player object from an explosion and from the force applied subtract health equivalent to the force applied

Im currently trying to use OnCollisionEnter and collision.relativeVelocity but i cant convert a Vector 3 to a float which im using for HP

```
//Class for player stats 
public static float HP =100f;

private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    Vector3 velocity = collision.relativeVelocity;
    HP = HP - velocity;
}

//Explosion force code (separate class form player stats)
    Vector3 ExplosionPosition = Bomba.transform.position;
    Collider[] colliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(ExplosionPosition, 
    radius);
    foreach (Collider hit in colliders)
    {
        Rigidbody RB = hit.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        if (RB != null)
        {
            RB.AddExplosionForce(power, ExplosionPosition, radius, 
            upForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your Vector3 to a float using the magnitude which represents the length of the vector.

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    Vector3 velocity = collision.relativeVelocity;
    HP = HP - velocity.magnitude;
}
```

EDIT:

Based on the comment, you may want to do the calculation yourself:

```
 float distance = (objPosition - explosionPosition).magnitude;
 if (distance > explosionRange){ return 0.0f; } // Out of reach        
 return 1.0f - distance / explosionRange;
```

this returns a linear decrease of the force. If distance is 0, you are on the explosion, you get the full force of 1. As you get further, the division gets closer to 1 and the value gets closer to 0.

Comment: So this works quite well however the issue ive noticed is that it doesnt pick up the velocity/force from the explosion, it does detect things such as fall damage though.